# How to define a polynomial using an array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm creating a program which will display useful information about a polynomial inputted by the user. I am storing the coefficient and exponent in an array named `arr`, where `arr[0, n]` are the coefficients and `arr[1, n]` are the exponents. Then I want to define the polynomial `fx` using the array.

I however can't find a way to get the `x` to stay undefined until I want to use the polynomial to, for example, plot the graph or find the roots.

I also want the program to define `fx` the first time, and then use this predetermined polynomial after that in case the user inputs high values. This is the best I have been able to do thus far, ask if you need more information.

```
fx=0

def f(x):

    global fx
    
    if fx==0:
        for b in range(arr.shape[1]):
            fx=fx+arr[0,b]*x**arr[1,b]
        return fx
    else:
        return fx
```

Basically I want the program to define `fx` as for example `2*x**3+4*x**2` so that I can use `fsolve` and `plt.plot`, and `f(x)` as the polynomial's y-value if I want to see specific x-values.

Comment: in most language you can't use variable without value. In Python it may need special module [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) for symbolic operations. And as I remeber it has also function to `fsolve` (or similar) to worth with symbols. See: [solver](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html?highlight=solve#module-sympy.solvers)

Comment: Are you looking for https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html ?

Comment: @furas That is what I was looking for, thank you, but im not able to substitute `Symbol('x')` with a numeric value. I tried `fx.subs({x:2})` but when I print 'fx' it still just prints the polynomial instead of the value of the polynomial.

Comment: I have not idea what you created with `Symbol` and how you use `subs` in code. But if you see examples in previous link [solver](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html?highlight=solve#module-sympy.solvers) thens you see that `sub()` needs two values `subs(symbol, value)`. And it may need to assign result to variable - `result = fx.subs(x, 2)` `print(result)`